# Problem Installing 11.2.0 on RHEL 7 64 Bit

Tags: oracle, linux, oracle-asm, redhat

I have problem in stalling Oracle ASM on RHEL 7, Please advice

```
 [root@localhost grid]# ./root.sh
Performing root user operation for Oracle 11g

The following environment variables are set as:
    ORACLE_OWNER= grid
    ORACLE_HOME=  /u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid

Enter the full pathname of the local bin directory: [/usr/local/bin]:
The contents of "dbhome" have not changed. No need to overwrite.
The contents of "oraenv" have not changed. No need to overwrite.
The contents of "coraenv" have not changed. No need to overwrite.

Entries will be added to the /etc/oratab file as needed by
Database Configuration Assistant when a database is created
Finished running generic part of root script.
Now product-specific root actions will be performed.
Using configuration parameter file: /u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/crs/install/crsconfig_params
Creating trace directory
LOCAL ADD MODE
Creating OCR keys for user 'grid', privgrp 'oinstall'..
Operation successful.
LOCAL ONLY MODE
Successfully accumulated necessary OCR keys.
Creating OCR keys for user 'root', privgrp 'root'..
Operation successful.
CRS-4664: Node lrma086 successfully pinned.
Adding Clusterware entries to inittab
ohasd failed to start
Failed to start the Clusterware. Last 20 lines of the alert log follow:
2015-10-19 10:19:43.306
[client(28082)]CRS-2101:The OLR was formatted using version 3.
2015-10-19 10:19:46.259
[client(28109)]CRS-1001:The OCR was formatted using version 3.
[client(28227)]CRS-10001:CRS-6021: No msg for has:crs-6021 [l][unlimited]
[client(28228)]CRS-10001:CRS-6021: No msg for has:crs-6021 [n][65536]

ohasd failed to start at /u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/crs/install/roothas.pl line 358, <ALERTLOG> line 6.
/u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/perl/bin/perl -I/u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/perl/lib -I/u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/crs/install /u01/app/grid/product/11.2.0/grid/crs/install/roothas.pl execution failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  was installing unsupported version, correct version for Linux 7.1 is 11.2.0.4

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/relnotes.112/e23558/toc.htm#CJAFHBIA

Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Support
Starting with Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.4), Oracle Linux 7 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 are supported on Linux x86-64.

Answer (score 1):

Cause

The security limits requirements were not set according the recommended values

The message
[client(15674)]CRS-10001:CRS-6021: No msg for has:crs-6021 [n][65536]
makes think about the value recommended for oracle hard nofile 65536 in /etc/security/limits.conf

Then these messages makes think that probably the other parameters in /etc/security/limits.conf were not set
[client(15669)]CRS-10001:CRS-6021: No msg for has:crs-6021 [l][unlimited]
[client(15672)]CRS-10001:CRS-6021: No msg for has:crs-6021 [c][unlimited]

Solution

Using root user make sure that /etc/security/limits.conf are set as follows
oracle soft nproc 2047
oracle hard nproc 16384
oracle soft nofile 1024
oracle hard nofile 65536
oracle soft stack 10240

Comment: oracle   soft   nofile    1024
oracle   hard   nofile    65536
oracle   soft   nproc    2047
oracle   hard   nproc    16384
oracle   soft   stack    10240
oracle   hard   stack    32768

Comment: I have those values still it shows the error, this is not the solution

Comment: Sorry to hear that, this is what documentation shows as the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug. You need to apply patch 18370031, please refer below URL for the steps.

https://fatdba.com/2016/01/06/oracle-gi-11-2-installation-on-rhel-7-error-ohasd-failed-to-start-failed-to-start-the-clusterware-last-20-lines-of-the-alert-log-follow-ohasd-failed-to-start-at-u01app11-2-0gridcrsinstallr/

Comment: Could you add some additional information to your answer? Link only answers tend to become obsolete or orphaned when the target site ceases to exist. Thank you.